# I have an array of doubles that I need to get a median but it keeps giving me an int conversion error

Tags: java, arrays, int, double

I have no idea how to get the median without this method, but it keeps saying conversion error.  I know it's because I'm dividing the numbers.length by 2, but I can't figure out how to make the program understand it's a double.  It's at the bottom where I keep getting the error. It's my last if else statement.  I have searched everywhere so I'm sorry if this is a repeat, but I couldn't find one.  I can't convert to ints either because my array consists of doubles.  Thanks in advance to whoever helps me.

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ComputingArrays
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        double [] numbers = {33.5, 67.5, 67.5, 88.0, 46.0, 94.5, 77.5, 83.0, 95.0, 80.5}; // declare, allocate memory, and store values

        double n = numbers.length; // get length of array
        Arrays.sort(numbers);
        System.out.println("The Array of Numbers are :");
        double sum = 0; //initiate and declare sum
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {  //loop through n numbers
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
            sum = sum + numbers[i];
        }      
        final double average = sum / n;
        System.out.println("The Sum of the Array is " + sum);
        System.out.println("The Average of the Array is " + average);

        double var1 = 0;
        double var2 = 0;
        double varSum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
            var1 = numbers[i] - average;            
            var2 = var1 * var1; // to square
            varSum = varSum + var2; // to get sum of all squared differences
        }
        double variance = varSum / n;
        System.out.printf("The Variance of the Array is  %.2f %n", variance); //%.2f rounds two decimal places 

        System.out.printf("The Standard Deviation is %.3f %n", Math.sqrt(variance));

        double middle = numbers.length / 2.0;
        double median = 0.0;
        if (numbers.length % 2 == 1){
            median = numbers[middle];
            System.out.println("The median is " + median);
        }
        else {
            median = (numbers[middle-1] + numbers[middle]) / 2;
            System.out.println("The median is " + median);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you divide by `2.0` instead of `2`?

Comment: I actually just edited my post to put that in there instead.  It doesn't work either.

Comment: You're also indexing an array using doubles which is a bit strange... `middle` should be an `int`. Try printing the value of `middle`.

Comment: You can explicitly declare `middle` as `int` like d.j.brown suggested. Or you can cast it as integer `int middleAsInt = (int)middle;` and then use `middleAsInt`. Basically you are getting the error because you are trying to use the double as an index and an index in the array should always be int.

Comment: My teacher wanted us to use those numbers specifically for degrees and I thought it was weird to use doubles in an array, if that's what you mean.  When I tried printing the value of middle, nothing comes out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        double [] numbers = {33.5, 67.5, 67.5, 88.0, 46.0, 94.5, 77.5, 83.0, 95.0, 80.5}; // declare, allocate memory, and store values

    double n = numbers.length; // get length of array
    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    System.out.println("The Array of Numbers are :");
    double sum = 0; //initiate and declare sum
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {  //loop through n numbers
        System.out.println(numbers[i]);
        sum = sum + numbers[i];
    }      
    final double average = sum / n;
    System.out.println("The Sum of the Array is " + sum);
    System.out.println("The Average of the Array is " + average);

    double var1 = 0;
    double var2 = 0;
    double varSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
        var1 = numbers[i] - average;            
        var2 = var1 * var1; // to square
        varSum = varSum + var2; // to get sum of all squared differences
    }
    double variance = varSum / n;
    System.out.printf("The Variance of the Array is  %.2f %n", variance); //%.2f rounds two decimal places 

    System.out.printf("The Standard Deviation is %.3f %n", Math.sqrt(variance));

    double middle = numbers.length / 2.0;
    double median = 0.0;
    int middleIndex = (int)middle;
    if (numbers.length % 2 == 1){
        median = numbers[middleIndex];
        System.out.println("The median is " + median);
    }
    else {
        median = (numbers[middleIndex-1] + numbers[middleIndex]) / 2;
        System.out.println("The median is " + median);
    }
}
}
```

**This prints out:**

The Sum of the Array is 733.0
The Average of the Array is 73.3
The Variance of the Array is  369.66
The Standard Deviation is 19.227
The median is 79.0

Answer (score 1):

You should make the variable n as int.Array length is always going to be int
Your problem is that you are making the variable middle double.later calling that variable as the index number.but index number can only be int.

Comment: Do you mean to write it like int n = numbers.length?  I tried that just now and also tried to change the doubles middle and median to ints but it's still giving me the error.  I think it's because my array is doubles, but those are the numbers our teacher told us to use.

Answer (score 1):

When indexing an array it requires an `int` and not a `double`, for the very reason that a value such as `5.5` is not a valid index.

**Valid**

```
int middle = numbers.length / 2;
System.out.println(numbers[middle]);
```

**Invalid**

```
double middle = numbers.length / 2.0;
System.out.println(numbers[middle]);
```

Comment: Oops. Sorry I didn't mean to hit enter.  It's still saying conversion error.  Is it because I have doubles in my array?